# Redis delete perfomance

Tags: php, performance, redis

I have a queue on Redis - about 100 million inserts a day.
Redis insert rows is very well - works quickly and efficiently.

But when i try delete rows - is problem!

My part of php code:

```
$limit = 100000;

for ($ i = 1; $ i <= $ limit; $ i++) {

$ line = $ redis-> lPop ('my_list');

}
```

Its works, but deleting is very-very SLOW. 100K records = 100s.

How can I speed up the process?

Comment: `DEL my_list`, no? :)

Comment: This list queue of site's views. Redis used like temporary storage before record data in MySQL. I cant delete list, because inserts of views never stop.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue with the snippet is that it loops and sends each LPOP independently. Try using pipelining and I'm sure you'll see a definite gain in performance.

However, a much better solution to your problem would be to use Redis' [LREM](http://redis.io/commands/lrem) command that basically does what you want :)

Answer (score 0):

If do not care transaction，you can try  MULTI PIPELINE.

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

$pipe = $redis->multi(Redis::PIPELINE);
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){
    $pipe->lPop("key");

}
$pipe->exec();
```